# How to submit a form by clicking submit button only

Tags: php, html

I need to submit form by clicking submit button only. I don't want to submit form by pressing enter.

Here is my code.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>    

<script>
 $('#regForm').on('keyup keypress', function(e) {
 var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
   if (keyCode === 13) { 
     e.preventDefault();
     return false;
   }
 });
</script>

<form action="2.php" method="get" id="regForm">
 <input name="a" type="text" />
 <input name="b" type="text" />
 <input name="sub" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

`2.php` contains `var_dump($_GET);` But it will submit form after pressing enter key and clicking submit button

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are almost right, but small mistake. You need to **delegate** those events on the `input`s and not on the `<form>` itself:

```
$('#regForm').on('keyup keypress', "input", function(e) {
  var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
  if (keyCode === 13) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
});
```

The above code will not register <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

The same code as a working snippet:

```js
$(function () {
  $('#regForm').on('keyup keypress', "input", function(e) {
    var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if (keyCode === 13) {
      e.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="2.php" method="get" id="regForm">
  <input name="a" type="text" />
  <input name="b" type="text" />
  <input name="sub" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: @Mr.Shrestha Ha ha... That was just for fun. Don't worry. You can get rid of this. Does this work for you?

Comment: @Mr.Shrestha **Remove the `alert()` please!** And I have removed it for you! `:)`

Comment: @Mr.Shrestha Enjoy buddy. Happy to help you! `:)`